# FullCalendar javascript - refetchEvents not updating calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When I update the 'events' object with a new event and call calander.fullCalendar('refetchEvents') the calendar is not refreshed.

Example:

```
events = [ { title  : 'event1', start  : '2015-11-01' } ];
calendar = jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({ events: events });
events = [ { title  : 'event2', start  : '2015-11-02' } ];
console.log(events);
calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Still only shows 'event1' even though I expect 'event2' to show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/u1fjfbzw/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simplistic way to get event1 and event2 to both show up is add events array again as an event source. http://jsfiddle.net/u1fjfbzw/1/

```
events = [ { title  : 'event1', start  : '2015-11-01' } ];
calendar = jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({ events: events });
events = [ { title  : 'event2', start  : '2015-11-02' } ];

/* This will make it show up */
calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);

calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

The 'events' array in your code is separate from fullCalendar's internal events. From fullcalendar.js 2.4.0:

```
else if (typeof sourceInput === 'object') {
    source = $.extend({}, sourceInput); // shallow copy
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does 'refetchEvents' even do anything at that point? Seems like it is not necessary.

Comment: Nope, it is not needed; I overlooked that in the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) - addEventSource automatically fetches the events from the source.

Comment: Ok, so to clear the events I'll use removeEvents, then addEventSource. http://jsfiddle.net/u1fjfbzw/3/ I still don't understand the point of 'refetchEvents', I assumed it would do just that.

Comment: I believe refetchEvents is mainly useful for when using a json feed or function as the source of events. [Here's a function based demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u1fjfbzw/4/)